# Redirect traffic to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

For a development environment, I need to simulate an http server on a specific IP address(Redirect x.x.x.x to 127.0.0.1)

To test, I opened a simple server with Python

```
python3 -m http.server
```

And I was able to access it from Chrome successfully.

Then i tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
ufw reload
```

With the new address I could not access.

My enveroment:

- Ubuntu 20.04 x64
- ens33, lo
- Virtual machine (Network adapter conntected is unchecked)

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you were using -j REDIRECT ... rather than DNAT --to 127.0.0.1 it would work from remote (and without a lengthy explanation on why it doesn't etc). Do you really need specifically 127.0.0.1? Isn't the host's main address good enough since that python test listens on any address?

Answer (score 1):

Enable routing

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Enable forwarding to loopback interface

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

Redirect all traffic to loopback

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Enable NAT (aka Masqurade)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```